# WordPress - Different loading in normal and incognito browsing

Tags: wordpress, nginx, caching

We have recently installed on our Nginx server with PHP 7.3 a WordPress in the most recent version. Installation is correct at all times and problems arise when applying a template.

In normal browsing, you can see how the template has been applied correctly, but when you enter incognito browsing, you see everything by default, without changes.

Among the multiple tests we have restarted Nginx, purged WordPress cache and the server. We have made changes within the installation and the problems continue.

In this server we have several installations in WordPress and we have not had problems with these, simply with these clean installations. Has anyone had a similar problem?

[image]

[image]